# split the string based on array of chunk length

Tags: c#

This code is working for fixed size:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBy(this string str, int chunkLength)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) 
        throw new ArgumentException();

    if (chunkLength < 1) 
        throw new ArgumentException();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += chunkLength)
    {
        if (chunkLength + i > str.Length)
            chunkLength = str.Length - i;
    
        yield return str.Substring(i, chunkLength);
    }
}
```

This code is for splitting the string based on fixed `chunkLength`, for example 3.

But I need to modify split the string based on array of `chunksize`, for example 6, 3.

So I modify it slightly:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBy(this string str, int[] chunkLengths)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) 
        throw new ArgumentException();

    if (chunkLengths.Length < 1) 
        throw new ArgumentException();
           
    foreach (int chunkLength in chunkLengths)
    {
        int i = 0;

        if (chunkLength + i > str.Length)
            chunkLength = str.Length - i;

        yield return str.Substring(i, chunkLength);
        i += chunkLength;
    }
}
```

Usage:

This call is working:

```
var result = "bobjoecat".SplitBy(3);      // bob, joe, cat
```

This is what I need:

```
var result = "bobjoecat".SplitBy([6,3]);   // bobjoe, cat
```

Comment: Does the code not work? If not, can you explain what it does? If it does work, then what's your question?

Comment: the code does not work....can u pls provie me a idea

Comment: i need split string based on array value..

Comment: `int i = 0; inside the `foreach` creates a new variable `i` for each iteration of the loop, and sets it to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disregarding any other problem conceptual or otherwise, and purposely leaving out any fault tolerance and bounds checking

**Given**

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitBy(this string str, int[] chunkLengths)
{
   var offset = 0;
   foreach (var chunkLength in chunkLengths)
   {
      yield return str.Substring(offset, chunkLength);
      offset += chunkLength;
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var result = "bobjoecat".SplitBy(new []{6, 3});
foreach (var item in result)
   Console.WriteLine(item);
```

**Output**

```
bobjoe
cat
```

Note I would have just answered this in a comment with [**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r2VFUe), however the hamsters at .net fiddle seems to have died at the moment

Comment: This assumes that 1) the sum of the given chunk lengths equals the string length, and 2) that the string does not contain any Unicode surrogate pairs.

Comment: @KlausGütter see the first note in my answer